# MDX PeriodsToDate Function

Tags: sql, mdx

I am unable to get periodsToDate to work in MDX. I am getting the sum value when i am setting the periods to year level, but i am unable to get the sum values for quarters, months and days level.

### This is my query for the year level (which is working fine).

```
With MEMBER [Measures].[Cumul Claim Cost] AS
'Sum
(
PERIODSTODATE
(
[Valuation Date].[Year].[All].Level,
[Valuation Date].[Year].CurrentMember
)
,[Measures].[Cost]
)'

select 
    {[Measures].[Cumul Claim Cost], [Measures].[Cost]} on columns,
    {[Valuation Date].[Date].Members} on rows
    from [WVWC DATA CUBE FROI SROI]
```

And this is my query for days level which is not working.

```
With MEMBER [Measures].[Cumul Claim Cost] AS
'Sum
(
PERIODSTODATE
(
[Valuation Date].[Year].[All].Level,
[Valuation Date].[Year].[Month-Year].[Quarter- Year].[Date].CurrentMember
)
,[Measures].[Cost]
)'
select 
    {[Measures].[Cumul Claim Cost], [Measures].[Cost]} on columns,
    {[Valuation Date].[Date].Members} on rows
    from [WVWC DATA CUBE FROI SROI]
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind guys, I was able to get the correct query after tons of hit and trials.


> with MEMBER [Measures].[Cumul Claim Cost] AS 'Sum ( PERIODSTODATE (
> [Valuation Date].[All].level,
> 
>  [Valuation Date].CurrentMember ) ,[Measures].[Cost] )'
> 
> select   {[Measures].[Cumul Claim Cost], [Measures].[Cost]} on
> columns,  NON EMPTY {[Valuation Date].[Quarter- Year]} on rows  from
> [WVWC DATA CUBE FROI SROI]

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question then and include the solution, as in the query, it can be formatted to be better readable than in a comment. This would benefit future readers of your question who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermin guys, I was able to get the correct query after tons of hit and trials.

> with MEMBER [Measures].[Cumul Claim Cost] AS 'Sum ( PERIODSTODATE (
>   [Valuation Date].[All].level,
>
> [Valuation Date].CurrentMember ) ,[Measures].[Cost] )'
>
> select    {[Measures].[Cumul Claim Cost], [Measures].[Cost]} on
>   columns,  NON EMPTY {[Valuation Date].[Quarter- Year]} on rows    from
>   [WVWC DATA CUBE FROI SROI]