# Date dimension and cumulative Months

Tags: sql, database-design, ssas, data-warehouse, olap

The Date dimension is in the following state:

[image: Date dimension]

In `SSAS` looks like this:
[image]

**Based on this how can I build an Hierarchy in `SSAS` with the following** **structrue:**

```
2016
   Jan-Feb
   Jan-Mrz
   Jan-Apr
   Jan-Mai
   Jan-Jun
```

**...**
**where `Jan-Apr` will be the cumulative Amount from January until April in 2016.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downvotes are probably because this is a bad dimension design.  You can get a cumulative aggregation by dropping all this Jan-Feb etc stuff, using a simple Date dimension and using the [PeriodsToDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503291/mdx-periodstodate-function) function.

Comment: yes, but I need this structure as a hierarchy or a set, not as a calculated member... I need to filter it

Comment: as a calculated member I user the following mdx query:                                                                 Aggregate
(
  PeriodsToDate
  (
     [Date].[Hierarchy].[Year],
  [Date].[Hierarchy].[Month].CurrentMember
  ),
  [Measures].[Measures].[Amount]
)

Comment: If you need that dimension structure (though I can't imagine why), you still don't need all those extra columns.  A simple Months dimension, with an extra dimension attribute "YTD Description", with same cardinality as the Months, will work.  e.g. dimension member "April" would have YTD Description attribute "Jan-Apr".  You can then use PeriodsToDate, or Head() on a month number.

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy should go as Year -> Month -> day and so on. To support cummilative figures combine your hierarchy with a range dimension that includes month ranges like Jan - Apr for example. Hierarchy is not used as ranges directly. you have to combine both together to get the requirement.

Range dimension will have minimum value which will be your starting month and max value which will be your ending month of one particular range. Example dimension as follows

> `+------------+---------------------+
>   | DIM_Range                        |
>   +------------+---------------------+
>   |Sur_Key | Min Value  | Max Value  |
>   +------------+---------------------+
>   | 01     | Jan        | Apr        |
>   | 02     | May        | August     |
>   +------------+---------------------+`